# Spring Boot app getting Closed after working for few days in Tomcat deplayed as WAR

Tags: spring, spring-boot, war, tomcat8

error Logs
**please see the below tomcat standard output logs**:

[image]

Not Sure what causing this issue..

Comment: Is it just the Spring Boot app that is being stopped or the entire Tomcat instance?